# Feign with Ribbon and Hystrix

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, hystrix, spring-cloud-feign

Hystrix is not opening the circuit for the feign client. I am testing the server which is always slow with following configuration:

```
hystrix.circuitBreaker.requestVolumeThreshold: 4
hystrix.circuitBreaker.errorThresholdPercentage: 50
hystrix.circuitBreaker.sleepWindowInMilliseconds: 7000
hystrix.metrics.rollingStats.timeInMilliseconds: 15000
hystrix.metrics.rollingStats.numBuckets: 5
hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds: 31000

feign:
    hystrix:
        enabled: true

organizationService:
  ribbon:
    MaxAutoRetries: 3
    MaxAutoRetriesNextServer: 0
    OkToRetryOnAllOperations: true
    ConnectTimeout: 10000
    ReadTimeout: 1000
```

I can see 4 retry and java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out error after that but when I am checking the Turbine it shows Circuit Closed for the operation.

Comment: what also matters is these 4 requests happened over how many seconds?. because u have specified hystrix.metrics.rollingStats.timeInMilliseconds: 15000. which means , your circuit will be open only if more than 4 requests fail within a window of 15 seconds. And also once it is open, it will be open only for 7 seconds(hystrix.circuitBreaker.sleepWindowInMilliseconds: 7000).  So the question, when u check in Turbine about the circuit, are you sure you are checking at the right time

Comment: 1. yes, 1 call tekes 1 sec (read time out) and 4 call happens in 4 sec. all fails.
2. I checked turbine at the same moment in another window.